# UWP InkToolbar: How to make eraser types like those in Windows Sketchpad

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I want to make eraser types like those in Windows 10 Creators Update Sketchpad , that include not only stroke eraser but also small or large erasers.

[image]

Currently, the default InkToolbar control only provide stroke eraser, the user can only erase the entire stroke but not a part of it. And Windows Universal Samples on GitHub is not providing any samples on that.

Does anyone know how to make custom eraser types?

Comment: Hello @Edi dashen.I think you can set the eraser size but my vs bugongzuole that I cant confirm my way.

Comment: Do you use the `StrokeContainer` to draw the line? If so, we can only remove the line. We can not remove a part of the line.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Yes, I use the StrokeContainer. Thanks for telling me that, I know this is a limitation in StrokeContainer now. But can we have any samples for how to erase a part of the line on Windows Universal Samples repository? I really don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can have a look at Microsoft's Coloring book sample where you can erase cell(Portion of stroke). They have created a Custom InkToolbar with erase cell option.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-coloringbook